# How do I replace Windows Boot Manager with Grub2?

Tags: 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 with grub2 on an external ssd and installed grub to my internal windows efi partition.

The problem is that whenever I boot my laptop without external ssd neither windows boot manager nor grub2 will show up, instead i get grub command line which I have to `exit` before windows-bootmanager shows up.

Grub2 on the other side will only show up if I plug my external ssd in.

What I'd like to achieve is to have grub2 load even without ubuntu ssd plugged in.

Is this possible?

Comment: That may not work... as GRUB is installed as the boot loader, and part of GRUB ends up in the EFI partition, and the other part gets installed on your external SSD. With the SSD not connected, the missing part of GRUB is why you end up at the GRUB command line. Somebody prove me wrong?

Comment: you should be able to get into your bios and set windows as the 1st boot option. When you connect your usb you will have to use the boot menu to select Ubuntu and then it will bring up your grub menu (keys for both vary by motherboard so I cannot say which keys you need for sure)

Comment: My comment will not *replace* WBM with grub but it will stop you from having to exit grub every time. It is probably the best solution for what you want to accomplish

Comment: @heynnema that is partly correct the kernel boot info is installed in the efi partition and the rest of grub is installed in `/boot/grub`  The WBM is still there but grub is now selected as the default boot manager.  It is possible to work around.  One option that might work is to make Windows the preferred option in grub so it will chain-load into WBM instead of `/boot/grub`  the easier is to just make WBM the preferred option in the UFEI boot menu and use the boot menu for booting into grub when the usb disk is connected.

Comment: @TrailRider don't forget /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d :-)  Might just be easier to use bcdedit/bootedit to restore the WBM on the internal Windows only HDD, and install GRUB on the external Ubuntu SSD, and then use the BIOS/EFI F12 boot menu to select either drive to boot.

Comment: I meant bcdedit/bootrec.

Comment: @heynnema there is no need to restore WBM it is still on the efi partition or exit on grub would not work.  you could just remove the grub option with efibootmngr but that it not a risk I want to tell a new user to attempt, that is why I suggested trying to just set WBM as default.  Not as elegant but much safer.

Comment: @heynnema and TrailRider thank you both for your detailed explanations and solutions.  That's what I actually found out too, to reset my primary boot device to WBM and skip grub command line this way.  Only annoying thing is that I have now grub on my internal ssd and can't use it properly. Should have installed it on my external drive. Next time I will pay attention.

Comment: @juicypop The little remaining parts of GRUB are only in the EFI partition on your Windows drive. No big deal. You should be able to install GRUB on the external Ubuntu drive. Then you can directly boot to either drive from the F12 boot menu.

Comment: @heynnema thanks again. I managed to switch back to WBM and if I boot my USB stick grub shows up. It's just annoying I have to f12 into select boot medium. Back in the days everything seemed a little more convenient :)

Comment: @juicypop Keep in mind that your setup is not standard. You have OS's on separate disks, two different boot loaders, and you want to be able to boot Windows when the USB drive is not connected. If it was all on one disk, this would be much simpler :-)

Comment: See bugs 1396379 and 1173457, and do add yourself to the "Does this affect me" list (click on the yellow icon). https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the answer. Unfortunately my reputation is to low to vote publicly on it ;(

Answer (score 0):

**Note that this is a non-standard dual-boot installation...**

- Windows on internal HDD/SSD
- Ubuntu on external USB SSD
- Pre-req that Windows can boot when the external SSD is not connected

**The procedure to make this work is...**

- Re-enable Windows Boot Manager on the Windows internal HDD/SSD
- Install GRUB on the Ubuntu external SSD
- Set the UEFI boot order to boot the internal HDD/SSD first
- If required, use the F12 BIOS/EFI boot menu to select which OS to boot at power on

Comment: If you want UEFI boot on external, you have to have an ESP on external. You can install grub to external then as now it also creates /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is how external drives boot in UEFI mode. Full grub using bootx64.efi also needs /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP for additional files. You have to use the --removable parameter when installing grub to external.